# Kubernetes : Launch a single container inside existing cluster, for running cron jobs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cron

I am working on Kubernetes cluster, where I want to run a single container which runs cron jobs. In the same cluster, I am deploying 3 other containers, which run app-code. What are the changes required just to add a different type of container in the same cluster?

service.yaml :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: supplier-service
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: supplier-service-instance
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/component: backend
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl
  annotations:
      # Note that the backend talks over HTTP.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
       # TODO: Fill in with the ARN of your certificate.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: OUR_ARN
       # Only run SSL on the port named "https" below.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-redirect-http-to-https: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-ports: "443"
  name: supplier-service

spec:
  selector:
    app: supplier-service
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
```

deployment.yaml -- this Yaml file runs app-code

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: supplier-service
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: supplier-service-instance
    app.kubernetes.io/version: '1.0.0'
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl
  name: supplier-service-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  strategy:
     type: RollingUpdate
     rollingUpdate:
        maxUnavailable: 25%
        maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: supplier-service
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: supplier-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: IMAGE-FROM-ECR/supplier-service:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: supplier-service
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
            - containerPort: 6379
```

I have a new DockerFile ready which installs cron jobs inside the container.

deployment-cron.yaml :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: supplier-service
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: supplier-service-instance
    app.kubernetes.io/version: '1.0.0'
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl
  name: supplier-service-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
     type: RollingUpdate
     rollingUpdate:
        maxUnavailable: 25%
        maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: supplier-service
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: supplier-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: AWS-ECR/supplier-service-cron:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: supplier-service
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
            - containerPort: 6379
```

Is this the correct way to run a single container inside existing cluster, or are there any other changes required? Thank you. :-)

Comment: This will not work .. when you start first deployment with `deployment.yaml` with name `supplier-service-deployment` you will fail to deploy one more using `deployment-cron.yaml` with same name `supplier-service-deployment` .. what is your reason not to use [cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)

Comment: @D.T. : I don't want crons running on all containers, as these crons also send emails... If it runs on all containers, that many emails will be sent. :-)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you want to replace the existing container in a pod with a different container and it shouldn't work like that. Is the thing that you want to achieve is to create a one pod that will cycle through all the pods with your app? What does your `supplier-service-cron` do?

Answer (score 0):

**Above approach will throw an error to you when you try to deploy two deployments with same name in same namespace.**

Example of what you are trying to do is as below

$ cat deploy1.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    deployment1: One
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      deployment1: One
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        deployment1: One
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

$ cat deploy2.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    deployment2: Two
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      deployment2: Two
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        deployment2: Two
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Create first deployment.

```
$ kubectl create -f deploy1.yaml
deployment.apps/nginx created
```

Create second in same namespace and **you should see this error**.

```
$ kubectl create -f deploy2.yaml
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "deploy2.yaml": deployments.apps "nginx" already exists
```

Comment: What is the alternative?

Comment: As i understand from your example you have a seprate image used for the container firing the emails, so you should deploy it as a cronjob [refer automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) .. and please explain the complete use case what you are trying to achive .. from the look of above you are trying to inject a container inside a running POD but the objective is not very clear.

Comment: The problem is, if there are 5 containers running, and all of them will have cron-jobs running, then 5 emails will be sent out... these cron jobs send out emails.... That's why the requirement of a seperate container which only runs cron jobs. :-) Crons are working with the new DockerFile which I mentioned, so no issues on Docker side. :-)

Comment: that why i recommend use of cronjobs which will create a single container to fire email as you need . I believe you are still short of explaining the complete end to end use case on your question.

Answer (score 0):

The naming and labels need to be changed from the original deployment yaml.

If you leave `metadata.name` the same, you would modify the existing deployment on a `kubectl apply -f` rather than creating a new deployment.

I don't think you need the ports if all your running is cron, unless it's running a full instance of the `supplier-service`

The existing `Service` selector would get confused if you leave the label `app: supplier-service` on your cron container.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: supplier-service
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: supplier-service-instance
    app.kubernetes.io/version: '1.0.0'
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl
  name: supplier-service-cron-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: supplier-service-cron
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: supplier-service-cron
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: AWS-ECR/supplier-service-cron:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: supplier-service-cron
```

Also kubernetes provides a standalone [cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) functionality in case you weren't aware.